# Reduce height of the complete outlined mat-form-field in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-form-field

Here is the basic code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      Search Here
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: hello welcome to stackoverflow please follow [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask your question